# Multiple vim regex command in one line

Tags: regex, vim

I want to run ,multiple regex commands in pipe on gvim.

for example:

```
s/,/;
s/\v\[(\d+):0\]/\=submatch(1)+1/g
```

how can i implement it in one line? does gvim support two regex commands in pipe?

i tried to run:

```
s/,/; | s/\v\[(\d+):0\]/\=submatch(1)+1/g
```

however it doesn't work for me.

hope for help

thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

> does gvim support two regex commands in pipe?

"Bars" are not about "regexes". They are about individual commands (see `:h :bar` for a complete list; also you may want to read `:h cmdline-lines` in full). But it actually works for `:s`, as per Vim's help: "*Note that this is confusing (inherited from Vi): With ":g" the '|' is included in the command, with ":s" it is not.*"

> however it doesn't work for me

That's because you **must** close the first regex before starting the second command: `:s/,/;/ | ...`

But in general, if you need to have "a bar" after a command which forcefully treats it as an argument, you can quote it with `:h :execute`, like this: `execute 'cmd1' | cmd2`. Beware of extra quoting single-quotes though.

Comment: Thanks! i tried to run: :execute 'retab' | s/ddd/aaa and it still doesn't work for me...

Comment: @IdanRahamim "doesn't work for me" is like saying nothing, because it certainly does do _something_. And if it isn't what you expect then you must first say _what_ exactly you do expect. So far I can only guess that you don't know the difference between `s/aaa/bbb` and `%s/aaa/bbb/g`, but I might be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple command in one line You have to do this:

```
:command1 | :command2 | :command3 | and more...
```

for example

```
:retab | :%s/match/replace/g | :let tmp = 'something text' | :echo tmp
```

Don't forget the colon before the command